# Determination of bearing change between two points (spatial-data)

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude, spatial, bearing, spatial-data

I am reviewing a paper on transportation mode to understand their methodology (this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0968090X17303509)). At some stage, the authors computed the rate of bearing change between the points (GPS points), which happens to be a stumbling block to me, for days, I really can't figure out how they derived the equations.

Specifically, this is how they demonstrated it (illustrating bearing of p2 from p1 from true north).

[image: figure]

As usual, papers are not books, so most concepts are assumed to be known by readers, they went ahead to list the following equations, stating...

```
"The bearing rate is the absolute difference between the bearings of two consecutive points, which are calculated as follows:"
```

[image: equtions]

I have been playing around with my little "trigonometry" but I really can't figure out how the equations were derived. Does anyone out there understand this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I landed at the right place, [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). I wish I could save someone's time looking for this.